# Change Wordpress Category Widget Placeholder Text?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget, categories

I have tried all the solutions on this site, but none seem to work, so starting a new thread.

I am trying to change the placeholder text on the Wordpress Category Widget. Currently it defaults to 'Select Category'.

I have tried adding below code to functions.php and I've also tried creating a specific plugin with this code, but hasn't worked. I also changed the widget's core code.

```
function ChangeSelectTitle($cat_args){
    $cat_args['show_option_none'] = __('My Category');
    return $cat_args;
}
add_filter('widget_categories_dropdown_args', 'ChangeSelectTitle');
```

Comment: What else have you tried? The more information you can provide, the likelier you are to get a decent answer. You will also likely need to add more code, as well as what happened when you changed your code to what it is currently.